Concentration inequality based on entropy of probability distribution?
I have $n$ bounded iid variables $X_i$. Suppose also have a discrete probability $p_i$ with $1 \le i \le n$ which I have a lower bound on the entropy for, called $h$.
Is there a way to get a concentration inequality on $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_iX_i$? My intuition is that the higher my entropy the better you should expect such an inequality to be, with obviously the case of $p_{i} = \frac{1}{n}$ being Hoeffding.

who is $h$? the distribution of $\sum p_iX_1?$

@LetacGérard Sorry, ambiguous wording, $h$ is my lower bound for the entropy of the discrete probability $p_i$. I want to express concentration inequality in terms of $h$
